# CentOS 7 : How to increase disk space with additional disk so as if there was only one disk?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, centos

I have a VPS running CentOS 7 with an original 10 GB disk on which everything is installed `/dev/vba1`and formatted in `xfs`.

I ordered from my provider an additional 50 GB disk that I need to format and configure to use.

The reason for that increase is that I have a website where people upload files and the first disk was getting full very fast.

I'd like to know if it's possible to add that new disk as if it were just an extension of the first disk. Meaning I'd like to add it as if there was only one disk so that when the first disk's capacity is maxed out, files written in the same folder will start going on the new disk.

Basically I want to avoid moving the website to the new disk and make it so that it's transparent whether files go on one disk or the other. I just need more space to store the files.

And if it's possible, what are the steps to do so ?

Comment: Depends. If your original volume is a logical volume, then yes. But it will require taking the server offline and having console / single user access. As this is a VPS, I'm guessing you may not have that option.

Comment: Exactly because this is a VPS, it should be possible to do this from the host system. You should ask your provider whether he is willing to do this. There are simple guides all over the internet.

Comment: My provider said I can put the VPS in rescue mode so that it runs on RAM instead of disk. I asked them the question directly if they could do it so that the second disk extends the original one, but they said it's actually two separate disks. The guy said that it should be possible to link them in some way though. @MariusMatutiae what should I search for to find one these guides ?

Comment: Try  something like *enlarge a disk in virtualbox* or *enlarge a disk  in VMWare*.